# Migrate magento 1 to magento 2 new column

Tags: magento2, magento-1, magento2-migration-tool, column

I'm trying to migrate from Magento 1.7.0.2 to Magento 2.3.1

For that I use the migration tool :https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-install.html

All is working fine except a custom table.

[image]

I get this message for the col4 when i launch the import :

- Destination fields are not mapped. Document: my_table. Fields: col4

I tried to fix thix with ignore and transform with no success :

```
    //file map.xml
<source>    
    <field_rules>
        <ignore>
            <field>my_table.col4</field>
        </ignore>
        <transform>
            <field>my_table.col4</field>
            <handler class="\Migration\Handler\SetValue">
                <param name="value" value="1" />
            </handler>
        </transform>
    </field_rules>
</source>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I was in source instead of destination.

```
<destination>
    <field_rules>
        <ignore>
            <field>my_table.col4</field>
        </ignore>
    </field_rules>
</destination>
```